# Checking each character in a string with regex - python

Tags: python, regex

I want to check a string and confirm it only has upper or lowercase alphabetical characters aswell as underscores.
I have this so far but I am getting errors

```
import re

def addPlayer():
    print("\nEnter the players name:")
    playerName = input()

    for x in range(len(playerName)):
        if re.match("[a-zA-Z_]", x):
            return
        else:
            print("Error: Please enter a valid name.")
            addPlayer()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "player.py", line 9, in addPlayer
    if re.match("[a-zA-Z_]", x):
  File "c:.....Python\Python38-32\lib\re.py", line 189, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: You're passing `x` to the match function, and `x` is an integer.  Perhaps you meant `playerName[x]`?

Comment: Also, since you don't have a `break` in the `else` branch, it's going to continue checking the characters after it returns from calling itself recursively.  Presumably you don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your entire username at once by checking that *all* the characters in the string are in the character class `[A-Za-z_]` i.e.

```
import re

def addPlayer():
    print("\nEnter the players name:")
    playerName = input()

    if not re.match(r'^[A-Za-z_]+$', playerName):
        print("Error: Please enter a valid name.")
        addPlayer()
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` is number and you passed it to `re.match`

Your for loop should be like this:

```
for char in playerName:
    if re.match("[a-zA-Z_]", char):
        return
    else:
        print("Error: Please enter a valid name.")
        addPlayer()
```

or event better

```
regex = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z_]')
print(not bool(regex.search("abs123"))) # does not match
print(not bool(regex.search("abs"))) # match
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the literal cause of that error is that x in an integer. So re.match(pattern, str(x)) fixes the error message. With that said, here is another (perhaps simpler) way to do this:

```
valid_chars = set([*string.ascii_uppercase, *string.ascii_lowercase, "_"])

for char in string:
    if char not in valid_chars:
        # Error Condition
## Acceptance Condition
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont nee

```
import re

def addPlayer():

    playerName='testT_'

    m = re.match("[\w_]", playerName)
    if m:
      print("Success")
    else:
      print("Error: Please enter a valid name.")
```

Comment: `\w` already includes `_`, but it also includes digits, which OP doesn't want

Answer (score 0):

```
    for x in range(len(playerName)):
        if re.match("[a-zA-Z_]", x):
            return
```

x's type is int, not string.

you can use

```
    for x in playerName:
        if re.match("[a-zA-Z_]", x):
            pass
```

or

```
for x in playerName:
    if not x in string.ascii_letters+'_':
        print("Error: Please enter a valid name.")
        addPlayer()
```